# Python: Using schedule library with a class fuction

Tags: python

> > I am new to Python.

Trying to implement `schedule` library to run a cron job. It is a simplistic library which does the basic job. 
 Calling a function like this work fine:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am not able to figure out how to call the function from a class. Tried doing like this but while loop doesn't work:

```
import schedule
import time

class Recommendation:

    def job(self):
        print "I'm working"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rec = Recommendation()
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(rec.job())
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually calling the `job` method instead of just passing it in your class based solution.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rec = Recommendation()
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(rec.job) # not `rec.job()`
    ...
```

Comment: old `java` habits die hard. Thanks for the prompt answer.